# Django Got an unexpected keyword argument 'id_speaker'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

I have a template that shows a list of speaker names that are urls, I want to click on these urls and go to the speaker page, I get the speaker by a unique id that looks like this "832fc2ca-787f-484b-b815-f82959607311", the problem is that I get the error

> get_speaker_by_id() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id_speaker'

I think the problem is ether on urls.py or the speakers.html href. I looked at every relative question but I couldn't file a solution.

urls.py

```
url(r'^speakers', views.speakers_list, name='speakers'),
url(r'^speaker/(?P<id_speaker>[0-9a-z\-]+)/$',
    views.get_speaker_by_id, name='get_speaker_by_id_url')
```

This is the template that shows the list of speaker names

speakers.html

```
{% for speaker in all_speakers_list%}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <a href="{% url 'get_speaker_by_id_url' speaker.speaker_id %}">{{ speaker.greek_name }}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
get_speaker_by_id(request, id_speaker):
    ''' Get speaker info by id '''
    requested_speaker = Speaker.objects.get(speaker_id=id_speaker)
    template = loader.get_template('greekparliament/speaker.html')

    context = {
        'requested_speaker': requested_speaker
    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

models.py

```
class Speaker(models.Model):
    speaker_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    english_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, default='', blank=True)
    wiki_el = models.URLField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True)
    greek_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    wiki_en = models.URLField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you make sure that you have not defined `get_speaker_by_id() ` more that one time in your views.py file? There may be a possibility that you have defined `get_speaker_by_id() ` more than one time and in the second time you have not define any `id_speaker` parameter

Comment: Yes! I can't believe I did this mistake. Thank you very much. Maybe post your this as an answer so I can mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we see the following error

```
get_speaker_by_id() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id_speaker'
```

we can clearly see that it is looking for an argument named `id_speaker`.

From the code of `views.py` file that you posted, I can clearly see that argument `id_speaker` is passed. Hence only one thing is possible for that error to be generated and that is **you HAVE defined function `get_speaker_by_id()` more than one time** in your `views.py` file.

P.S.
Change code of the function `get_speaker_by_id()` by the below code which has best practices implemented.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

...

def get_speaker_by_id(request, id_speaker):
    """
    Get speaker info by id <You should always write doc>
    For example, you can follow numpy guidelines on how to 
    write docs - https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt     

    Parameters
    ----------
    request
        Django request that will come from http

    id_speaker: str
        Id of the speaker

    """
    # I think you should handle `DoesNotExist` error here or it will crash
    # with an Internal Server Error when id_speaker does not exists in db
    requested_speaker = Speaker.objects.get(speaker_id=id_speaker)

    context = {
        'requested_speaker': requested_speaker
    }

    return render(request, "greekparliament/speaker.html", context)
```